# How to open a page from a GET request in a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable, get

I had a page with datatable in my Laravel app. I need to open a page with a number whose value I will receive in a GET request.

For example:

URL looks like `example.com/all?page=3` so DataTable should open page 3. But in fact DataTable open first page.

I try to catch value in `<script>` in my `all.blade.php` page:

```
<script>
    const parameter = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
    const values = parameter.split("=");
    const table = $('#zero_configuration_table').DataTable();

    $(document).on("load", function () {
        table.page(values[1]).draw(  );
    });
 </script>
```

In console I got error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

How to open a page using a parameter from a GET request?

UPD:
I added links to DataTable. The error from console has disappeared. But the DataTable does not open the right page for the GET request. Datatable shows `No data available in table`. It's work only for first page: `example.com/all?page=1` shows first page

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is the line to use to include dataTables with jquery. So you need both lines, 1 to include jquery and after that one for dataTables.

Comment: The error has disappeared. But the DataTable does not open the right page from the GET request. Datatable shows `No data available in table`

Comment: That's another error, not really relevant to this question. This has to do with rendering the data inside your table and display it.